# how to properly configure ODataModelBuilder to avoid conflict with virtual properties of model objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm building a self-hosted WebAPI 2 OData 4 service, using Db Context, which is reverse -engineered from an existing database.
The context looks like this:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using CommonDataService.Models.Mapping;

namespace CommonDataService.Models
{
    public partial class MALContext : DbContext
    {
        static MALContext()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<MALContext>(null);
        }

        public MALContext()
            : base("Name=MALContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AccountAlia> AccountAlias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AccountProgram> AccountPrograms { get; set; }
        public DbSet<AccountRolePerson> AccountRolePersons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChangeMeasure> ChangeMeasures { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Industry> Industries { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Offering> Offerings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Program> Programs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<RegionAlia> RegionAlias { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Tool> Tools { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountAliaMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountProgramMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountRolePersonMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new AccountMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ChangeMeasureMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CountryMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new IndustryMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OfferingMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PersonMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProgramMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegionAliaMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RegionMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RoleMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ServiceMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ToolMap());
        }
    }
}
```

In my startup.cs class I'm configuring my ODataModelBuilder in the following way:

```
ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<ChangeMeasure>("ChangeMeasure");
            builder.EntitySet<Account>("Account");
            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: null,
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());
```

One of my model classes "AccountAlia" looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CommonDataService.Models
{
    public partial class AccountAlia
    {
        public int AccountAlilasID { get; set; }
        public string AliasName { get; set; }
        public string SourceSystem { get; set; }
        public string SourceColumn { get; set; }
        public string SourceValue { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Account_ID { get; set; }
        public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to run my program, I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
occurred in System.Web.OData.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The complex type 'CommonDataService.Models.AccountAlia' 
refers to the entity type 'CommonDataService.Models.Account' 
through the property 'Account'.
```

What is the proper way for me to avoid such conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives a clue: The **complex type** 'X' refers to the **entity type** 'Y'. Currently, [OData for Web API does not support references to entity types from within complex types](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/65). See [The complex type 'MyData.AssetReading' refers to the entity type 'MyData.Asset' through the property 'Asset'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871565/the-complex-type-mydata-assetreading-refers-to-the-entity-type-mydata-asset).

But it looks to me like you intended `AccountAlia` to be an entity type. There is a spelling error that is preventing the `ODataConventionModelBuilder` from recognizing the key property of `AccountAlia`. Simply rename the property `AccountAlilasID` to `AccountAliaID` and the convention-based model builder will recognize `AccountAlia` as an entity type.